# How to make sure contents stays outside of tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, itemize

In my latex document, I have a tcolorbox environment for a definition, I set the parskip to be the baselineskip and I reset some spacing inside of lists. If I put an itemize environment under the tcolorbox, the item contents overlaps w/ the tcolorbox environment.

My working example is...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{nosep, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, before={\parskip=0pt},leftmargin=1.5em,label=\Large\textperiodcentered}

\usepackage{multido}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!5, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, breakable, boxrule=0.5pt]
    \noindent\sffamily\upshape \textbf{Definition}
    \ifx\empty#1\empty\else\ (#1)\fi. % Theorem name (optional)
    \ \ignorespaces
}
{
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \par\nobreak
}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[definition]
A definition
\end{definition}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The result is...
[image: result]

How do I make it so that the item contents stays outside the tcolorbox, without changing the paragraph separation I have already set?

Comment: the `\nobreak`in your environment

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

In Your definition change this line:

```
\vspace*{.5cm}\par\nobreak % >>>>> This line has changed
```